# CakePHP update table and associated table at the same time

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have two table that are related `strategies` and `strategy_conditions` strategies can have many strategy_conditions.

I have updated the strategies add.php with some javascript that I can add strategy_conditions to the page `<input type="text" name="strategies_conditions[0][name]" value="">` `<input type="text" name="strategies_conditions[1][name]" value="">` etc.

I want now to be able to edit the strategies_conditions at the same time on the strategies edit.php I can loop over and add the strategies_conditions inputs but my issue is that the name of the input is in the wrong format to the save. The input should be `<input type="text" name="strategies_conditions[0][name]" value="">` but instead it is `<input type="text" name="name" value="">`

here is the cakephp code

```
<div class="strategies form content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($strategy) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Edit Strategy') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->control('user_id', ['options' => $users]);
            echo $this->Form->control('name');
            echo $this->Form->control('description');
            echo $this->Form->control('one_hundred_trades');
        ?>
        <table id="conditions-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Level</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="condtitions-input"></input>
                        <select id="condtitions-level">
                            <option value="Mandatory">Mandatory</option>
                            <option value="Important">Important</option>
                            <option value="Support">Support</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="add-condtition" type='button' onclick="addCondition()">Add Conditions</button></td>
                    </td>  
                </tr>
                <?php foreach ($strategy->strategies_conditions as $strategiesConditions) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $this->Form->control('name', array( 'label' => false )); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>                       
            </thead>
        </table>                
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `$this->Form->control('name', array( 'label' => false ))` is asking it to generate a control called "name". Not sure why you'd think it would have anything else there?

Comment: You want to check **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#associated-form-inputs**

Comment: ok so if I use `name="strategies_conditions.0.name" ` it works. My problem is I need to find the correct index inside the `foreach`

Comment: Use [**key => value notation**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php): `... as $key => $strategiesConditions`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="strategies form content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($strategy) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Edit Strategy') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->control('user_id', ['options' => $users]);
            echo $this->Form->control('name');
            echo $this->Form->control('description');
            echo $this->Form->control('one_hundred_trades');
        ?>
        <table id="conditions-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Level</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="condtitions-input"></input>
                        <select id="condtitions-level">
                            <option value="Mandatory">Mandatory</option>
                            <option value="Important">Important</option>
                            <option value="Support">Support</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="add-condtition" type='button' onclick="addCondition()">Add Conditions</button></td>
                    </td>  
                </tr>
                <?php foreach ($strategy->strategies_conditions as $key => $strategiesConditions) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $this->Form->control('strategies_conditions.'.$key.'.name', array( 'label' => false )); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>                       
            </thead>
        </table>                
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```